# Do lambdas execute function parameters each iteration?

Tags: python, list, lambda

I am trying to use lambdas to apply to function over a list in python and was wondering if a lambda that is passed a function as a parameter executes that function parameter each iteration. For example:

```
func = lambda i, min, max: (i - min) / (max - min) 
arr = [func(i, min(arr), max(arr)) for i in arr]
```

Would this code block execute `min(arr)` and `max(arr)` each iteration of the for loop? If so, that would mean `min(arr)` and `max(arr)` are called `len(arr)` times which is redundant. If that is the case, would it be better to just save `min(arr)` and `max(arr)` and pass in the value to the lambda? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, in the list comprehension you are recalculating `min(arr)` and `max(arr)` for each element; and it would save your program some work if you put them in variables instead.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `lambda`. No matter what `func` was or how you defined it, `min(arr)` and `max(arr)` would be reexecuted on each iteration of the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in the list comprehension you are recalculating `min(arr)` and `max(arr)` for each element; and it would save your program some work if you put them in variables instead.

In fact, calculating the `min` or `max` is an O(n) operation, so precalculating them first changes this piece of code from O(n<sup>2</sup>) to O(n).

```py
imin = min(arr)
imax = max(arr)
arr = [func(i, imin, imax) for i in arr]
```